# Iteration is not writing on the right Array Index

Tags: java, arrays, iterator

I found a code that iterates trough a folder and return the fileNames.
I created a String[] Array with 8000 positions, since I have around 7500 files and getting more.
If I use the code that I found with system.out.println it returns every single file name, but if I use my code to write the position into the Array index, I only get 1 position and rest full of null.
Unlucky I cannot figure out the problem.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File folder = new File("mypath\\myfilefolder");
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
        String[] fileNames = new String[8000];

        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
            int c = 0;
          if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
              fileNames[c++] = listOfFiles[i].getName();
              // Seems not to be doing anything like supposed
    //      System.out.println(listOfFiles[i].getName());
    //      Prints every filename on a new line       
          } else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println("Directory " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
          }
        }

        for (String element: fileNames) {
            System.out.println(element);
        }
    }
}
```

I expect to be able to iterate trough fileNames and get the filesNames so I can work with it.
But actually only the first positions get changed, all the others are still null.

Comment: `int c = 0;` move that before the loop

Comment: Where are you moving c? you are always setting `int c = 0;` in the loop. So it will always be zero

Comment: Such a simple misstakes making so much trouble.... Thank you very much didn't even noticed that >.<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value changed at 'c++' is never used. Every time before your code execute to c++ the variable of c being reset to 0.

Answer (score 0):

And this would be the same algorithm with the use of the *stream API* (Java 1.8 and above):

```
String[] fileNames = Arrays.stream(folder.listFiles()) // stream all the files in the directory
    .filter(file -> !file.isDirectory()) // filter any directory files in there
    .map(File::getName) // map an item to its name
    .toArray(String[]::new); // collect as a String array
```